# Same project create two type SEO friendly url on Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm newbie on Yii, I'm facing some difficulties on create Yii SEO Friendly url.

My code is below:

```
echo CHtml::link($Menu->label, array('articles/view', 'id'=>$Menu->link,
```

This solution below config/main:

```
return array(
// ......
'components'=>array(
    // ......
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'articles/<id:\d+>-<t:.+>'=>'articles/view',
            // .......
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But this project created another url like below:

```
articles/view&id=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link'].
```

How to create SEO friendly url on this type link.

**Summery**

Same project create two type SEO friendly url

Thanks

Comment: add one moe parameter in array i.e. t after id parameter in chtml::link function

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
"articles/view/<id:([a-zA-Z0-9$&,':=?|.^*()%~!-]+)>" => "articles/view",
```

and call url as /articles/view/id/1